# Numpy reshape with remainder throws error

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, reshape, partitioning

How can I partition this array into arrays of length 3, with a padded or unpadded remainder (doesn't matter)

> >>> np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]).reshape([3,-1])
>
> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 11 into shape (3,newaxis)

Comment: Pad it first (with, say, `np.pad`) and then reshape.

Comment: do you know of a way to pad it to the nearest factor of 3? (or N)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
### Two Examples Without Padding

x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
desired_length = 3
num_splits = np.ceil(x.shape[0]/desired_length)

print(np.array_split(x, num_splits))

# Prints:
# [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10])]

x = np.arange(13)
desired_length = 3
num_splits = np.ceil(x.shape[0]/desired_length)

print(np.array_split(x, num_splits))

# Prints:
# [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10]), array([11, 12])]

### One Example With Padding

x = np.arange(13)
desired_length = 3
padding = int(num_splits*desired_length - x.shape[0])
x_pad = np.pad(x, (0,padding), 'constant', constant_values=0)

print(np.split(x_pad, num_splits))

# Prints:
# [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10, 11]), array([12,  0,  0])]
```

Comment: This does not work as expected for all lengths of `x`. If you do `x = np.arange(13)`, for example, you'll have 4 elements in the first array.

Comment: Good catch, it should be the ceiling and not rounding.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid padding with zeros, the most elegant way to do it might be slicing in a list comprehension:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(11)
>>> [x[i:i+3] for i in range(0, x.size, 3)]
[array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8]), array([ 9, 10])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pad with zeros, `ndarray.resize()` does this for you, but you have to figure out the size of the expected array yourself:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

cols = 3
rows = np.ceil(x.size / cols).astype(int)

x.resize((rows, cols))
print(x)
```

Which results in:

```
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10  0]]
```

As far as I can tell, this is hundreds of times faster than the list comprehension approach (see my other answer).

Note that if you do anything to `x` before resizing, you might run into an issue with 'references'. Either work on `x.copy()` or pass `refcheck=False` to `resize()`.

Comment: This is probably the best padding solution unless you are not allowed to resize.